# Unable to run sample Salesforce contact explorer application in Cordova project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: cordova, salesforce-sdk-android

In visual studio 2015 When I try to run the sample Salesforce contactexplorer application , I got the following error:

Here is my method:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
cordova.require("com.salesforce.util.logger").logToConsole("onDeviceReady:Cordova ready");
//Call getAuthCredentials to get the initial session credentials
cordova.require("com.salesforce.plugin.oauth").getAuthCredentials(salesforceSessionRefreshed, getAuthCredentialsError);
//register to receive notifications when autoRefreshOnForeground refreshes the sfdc session
document.addEventListener("salesforceSessionRefresh",salesforceSessionRefreshed,false);
//enable buttons
regLinkClickHandlers();
}
```

Here is my output:

```
> jslog: onDeviceReady: Cordova ready
> 
> missing exec:com.salesforce.oauth.getAuthCredentials
> 
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAuthCredentials' of undefined(…)
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAuthCredentials' of undefined
>     at module.exports.exec 
>     at exec (com.salesforce.util.exec.js:34)
>     at Object.getAuthCredentials (com.salesforce.plugin.oauth.js:56)
>     at onDeviceReady (index.html:64)
>     at Channel.fire (cordova.js:820)
>     at cordova.js:229 com.salesforce.oauth getAuthCredentials
```